# Desactivar un tab en Semantic UI

Tags: php, html, css, html5, semantic-ui

Sigo dandole a la implementación de **Semantic-UI** y estoy con un problemita que tendría que ver por qué no anda.

Resulta que tengo un sistema de 5 tabs que dependen de los ciertos valores que tomo de la base de datos. Uno de esos tabs es fijo, siempre se muestra pero los otros cuatro tabs representa un tipo de perfil de usuario. Si el usuario un tipo de usuario, pongamos "A", se muestra el tab y se deshabilitan los otros 3. Para ello hago lo siguiente:

```
<div class="ui top attached red inverted tabular menu">
        <a class="item active" data-tab="1">Datos Básicos</a>

      <?php
      foreach ($array as $key=> $values) {

        if($values == "1") { ?>
            <a class="item" data-tab="2">Perfil A</a>
          <?php } else{ ?>
            <a class="item disabled" data-tab="2">Perfil A</a>
          <?php }

          if($values == "2") { ?>
            <a class="item" data-tab="3">Perfil B</a>
          <?php } else{ ?>
            <a class="item disabled" data-tab="3">Perfil B</a>
          <?php }

          if($values == "3") { ?>
            <a class="item" data-tab="4">Perfil C</a>
          <?php } else{ ?>
            <a class="item disabled" data-tab="4">Perfil C</a>
          <?php }

          if($values == "4") { ?>
            <a class="item" data-tab="5">Perfil D</a>
          <?php } else{ ?>
            <a class="item disabled" data-tab="5">Perfil D</a>
          <?php }
    } ?>
    </div>
```

¿Que es lo que ocurre? Es como que se sombrean los tabs, pero si hago clic sobre el tab me muestra lo que hay en el. Cuando en realidad no debería dejar que eso ocurra.
Implemento algo que ya implemente en un select multiple hecho en **Semantic-UI** y que anda perfecto. No entiendo por que acá no funciona.

Por ejemplo un poco mas arriba hago esto:

```
$array = json_decode ($valorDevuelto, true);
var_dump($array);
```

Esto me devuelve:

```
array (size=3)
0 => string '1' (length=1)
1 => string '2' (length=1)
2 => string '4' (length=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que debes hacer es quitarle el atributo `data-tab` para que funcione la clase `disabled`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.item').tab();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.8/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.1.8/semantic.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" style="max-width: 80%; margin: 2em auto;">
    <div class="ui four item stackable tabs menu">
        <a class="item" data-tab="first">Primera</a>
        <a class="item" data-tab="second">Segunda</a>
        <span class="item disabled">tercera</span>
        <a class="item" data-tab="fourth">Cuarta</a>
    </div>

    <div class="ui tab" data-tab="first">
        Primer tab.
    </div>

    <div class="ui tab" data-tab="second">
        Segundo tab.
    </div>

    <div class="ui tab" data-tab="third">
        Tercer tab.
    </div>

    <div class="ui tab" data-tab="fourth">
        Cuarto tab.
    </div>
</div>
```

---

En cuanto a tu código PHP, estás repitiendo código HTML sin necesidad, podrías hacer algo así para cada elemento del tab (aunque se puede mejorar más aún):

```
<a class="item <?php echo $values == 1 ? '" data-tab="2' : 'disabled';?>">Perfil A</a>
```

Comment: Mmmmmmmmmm... gracias Shaz por responder... no estaría funcionando... ya que de la base de datos levanto los valores (1,2,4) y me habilita solo el tab 1... los otros dos los ignora, quedan deshabilitados e incaccesibles (eso esta bien) pero cuando quiero volver al tab basico (ahora lo renombre como el "0") no reacciona... no puedo acceder nuevamente a ese tab...

Comment: hice los reemplazos. Yo tenia: <a class="item disabled" data-tab="3">Perfil B</a> y lo reemplace por lo que me señalas: <span class="item disabled">Perfil B</span>. Perfecto, realmente me deshabilita el tab y no me deja hacer clic como quiero, pero ocurren dos cosas. La primera es que de la base de datos levanto el json 1, 2, 4 lo que significa que el tab 1, el tab 2 y el tab 4 deberían estar habilitados. Pues bien, solo queda habilitado el tab 1. Luego cuando quiero pasar al tab "0" no responde... no me deja hacer clic...

Comment: Bueno, eso ya realmente depende de como estás implementando tu código, no sé si sea asunto de PHP o de front-end, si te fijas, en el ejemplo que doy funciona perfectamente.

Comment: por ahi el control no soporta estar dentro de un for each...

Comment: Por lo que veo, tu implementación es un poco redundante y creo que de hecho el foreach no es necesario, simplemente puedes hacer una búsqueda con `in_array()`, sin necesidad de iterar.

Comment: fijate que mas arriba puse lo que me devuelve el json... y no es problema del json... y de como recorro el json: foreach ($array as $key=> $values) { y de acuerdo a los valores del $values analizo el comportamiento del tab

Comment: probe de usar in_array() y lo ignora todo... no me habilita ningun tab... peor que antes... ya vere que hago... gracias igualmente...

Comment: No entiendo como lo haces, con in_array() es mucho más fácil.

Comment: es lo mismo, me ahorro una linea de codigo...

Comment: Para nada, estás ahorrando iteraciones innecesarias con un foreach.  
¿Conoces DRY?

Comment: Con todo respeto creo que tu problema es más grande que activar o no un tab con Semantic UI, que es el alcance de esta pregunta y a lo cual respondí.

Comment: Desconozco tantas cosas, gracias a Dios... si apenas hace 3 meses que comencé con esto... si supiera todo lo que dices no estaría acá molestando para aprender...

Comment: Todos estamos aquí para aprender, no lo tomes personal, de hecho intento mostrarte otra forma de abordar la situación, de forma más global.

Answer (score 0):

Termine resolviendo el problema de una forma mas simple:

```
    $array = json_decode($valorDevuelto, true);
    ?>

    <div class="ui top attached red inverted tabular menu">
       <a class="item active" data-tab="0">Perfil Básico</a>
       <?php
       foreach ($array as $key=> $values) {
          if ($values == '1') { ?>
    <a class="item" data-tab="1">Perfil A</a>
  <?php }
  if ($values == '2') { ?>
    <a class="item" data-tab="2">Perfil B</a>
  <?php }
  if ($values == '3') { ?>
    <a class="item" data-tab="3">Perfil C</a>
  <?php }
  if ($values == '4') { ?>
    <a class="item" data-tab="3">Perfil D</a>
  <?php } }?>
  </div>
```

la idea es no complicarme deshabilitando o no una solapa tab, directamente no la muestro y es menos problemático...